# Map params is reordered in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query using script to sort the result, for my business, I need one params named cities to calculate the sort value, but when I use Debug.explain to print the params.cities, the order is not unexpected, it's reordered.

Is there anyone know how to use the correct order in script? thanks in advance for your help.

Query:

```
GET tour/product/_search
{
  "sort" : [
    {
      "_script" : {
        "script" : {
          "inline" : "Debug.explain(params.cities);",
          "lang" : "painless",
          "params" : {
            "cities" : {
              "2" : 100.0,
              "17" : 3.71,
              "12" : 3.63,
              "13" : 3.63,
              "14" : 3.6
            }
          }
        },
        "type" : "number",
        "order" : "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Print result:

```
{   "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "painless_explain_error",
        "reason": "painless_explain_error: null"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "tour-1",
        "node": "y5z7ah5cSoCk6n3Q95gbxw",
        "reason": {
          "type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "runtime error",
          "painless_class": "HashMap",
          "to_string": "{12=3.63, 2=100.0, 13=3.63, 14=3.6, 17=3.71}",
          "java_class": "java.util.HashMap",
          "script_stack": [
            "Debug.explain(params.cities);",
            "                    ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script": "Debug.explain(params.cities);",
          "lang": "painless",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "painless_explain_error",
            "reason": "painless_explain_error: null"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "script_exception",
      "reason": "runtime error",
      "painless_class": "HashMap",
      "to_string": "{12=3.63, 2=100.0, 13=3.63, 14=3.6, 17=3.71}",
      "java_class": "java.util.HashMap",
      "script_stack": [
        "Debug.explain(params.cities);",
        "                    ^---- HERE"
      ],
      "script": "Debug.explain(params.cities);",
      "lang": "painless",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "painless_explain_error",
        "reason": "painless_explain_error: null"
      }
    }   },   "status": 500 }
```

Comment: Maps are unordered by definition

Comment: Could I get any alternative solution to use an ordered map like ListOrderedMap in java?

Comment: Nothing prevents you to wrap `params.cities` in an ordered map